# Manipulating Hypothesis in Coq to prove (p → q) → (p → False) ∨ (q → False) → False

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm trying to prove prove (p → q) → (p → False) ∨ (q → False) → False, and part of my solution involves coming up with the hypothesis (True → True) → (True → False) ∨ (True → False) from (p → False) ∨ (q → False) → False. The idea is that (True → False) ∨ (True → False) should be False, so I could apply that to the goal False, so the goal would be True → True, which is True. I'm not sure how to implement this idea in coq; does anyone know how to? I thought maybe contradiction H0 would work to turn H0 into (True → True) → False, but to no avail. I've uploaded what I have in coq below. If this line of thinking is incorrect, could someone help lead me in the right direction? Thank you for your help. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAYm8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you cannot prove $\forall p, q: \text{Prop}, (p\to q)\to (p\to \text{False})\lor (q\to \text{False})$.

That proposition is not a tautology... and not what you want to prove.

Your goal should be $\forall p, q: \text{Prop}, (p\to q)\to (p\to \text{False})\lor (q\to \text{False})\to\text{False}$.

You missed the last $\to\text{False}$.

---

Also, the implicit bracketing should be $$\big((p\to q)\to(p\to\text{False})\big)\lor\big((q\to\text{False})\to\text{False}\big)$$

---

**Hint:** Use the definition that $\phi\to\text{False}\iff \lnot\phi$. Thus the statement of $\big((p\to q)\to(p\to\text{False})\big)\lor\big((q\to\text{False})\to\text{False}\big)$ is equivalent to $\big((p\to q)\to\lnot p\big)\lor \lnot\lnot q$.

Which says....

Comment: The implicit bracketing could be $(p\to q)\to\Big((p\to\text{False})\lor\big((q\to\text{False})\to\text{False}\big)\Big)$, which is also a tautology. In any case, the bracketing should have been explicit.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed.